# "A component with the name "ecSwapCppHdrFiles" already exists" on Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, rad-studio

When I right click on editor, IDE raises "A component with the name "ecSwapCppHdrFiles" already exists" exception.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by one of the 3rd party IDE plugins trying to add some own entries into the context menu. Try to find out which one it is and either get a newer version, disable that specific functionality (if possible) or get rid of it completely.

Comment: can you explain specifically how can i open context menu and what kind of entries I should try to add.

Comment: You shouldn't! The plugin tries to do that and produces that error. You need to find that plugin.